# What is the ideal travel for dual crown fork?

Tags: fork, suspension

I'm planning to have my fork upgraded. Currently I am using Suntour XCM with 100mm travel. I'm reading a lot of MTB forums and a lot of them are telling that you may break the head tube if you use dual crown fork with high travel(160-200mm). Based on their inputs, the ideal travel for a dual crown fork is around 130-140mm. My bike frame is a hard tail enduro. Any inputs will be appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

Given the frame is designed for 100mm fork, its unlikely its strong enough to handle riding that needs a 160+mm travel fork, and frame failure is possible. Its not the dual crown that is the problem - its riding a frame designed for 100 travel (typically XC) in a way that needs 200mm travel (typically extreme down hill).

Changing the fork travel changes the frame geometry and compromises handling. The original fork has 100mm, the bike is not designed for higher travel forks, anything more that about 120mm would starting to affect the handling. Above about 140mm, the bikes geometry would be all out of kilter, and it would be a completely different feel to what it is now.

For the same price, modern single crown forks in the 120-140mm travel are as good as any dual crown for enduro riding.  The original fork being a XCM100 also means its an entry level frame. I doubt the frame would benefit significantly from a decent dual crown fork over a decent single crown which would be nearly as stiff and lighter weight.

Adding all this together, if you really need more than 120mm travel, you would be better to buy a bike built for it. If you only need 120mm travel, a single crown fork will do the job best.

Comment: I appreciate such detailed answer. In addition to my question, are you telling that I should stay on 100mm travel fork rather than raising it? You are correct, my bike is an entry level MTB. I'm not really concerned with the travel as I will only use this bike for cross country. I'm mainly wanting to have dual crown fork for the looks, that's it.;) I want to have the same performance, same feel but the look of enduro MTB. I'm sorry for my ignorance, I'm quite new with MTB, i use to play with BMX before, i don't have any idea about forks.

Comment: I upgraded the fork on my entry level bike two years ago.  I wish I hadn't.  The new fork cost almost as much as the biked did and would have been 30-50% of a new bike (with the same fork).  It is a much better idea to just buy a new bike rather than upgrading forks on an entry level bike.  If you are like me, then next year you will want to upgrade something else.  At this point I could have bought two new bikes for the amount I have put into my current bike.

Answer (score 0):

I run a 170mm dual crown fork on my hardtail, it has been on the bike for a number of years, it is an awesome bike to ride and the frame is still going strong. It really depends on personal preference because the handling is changed quite considerably (in good ways and not so good), if you are racing or looking for optimum performance you are far better off keeping with what the frame was designed for. If you put a dual crown on a hardtail make sure you understand what type of riding the frame was designed for and you will not break it. The only way to find out is to try out some different bike setups and figure out what you enjoy and what suits your riding